# Gravity Forms Survey Score Value & Calculation

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

My issue is specific to Gravity Forms and the Survey Add-On

I'm trying to accomplish some calculations with the survey add-on outside of the built in "Survey Results" displayed in the form UI. Basically I have a survey with 3 categories of questions, 5 questions each, 15 questions total. Questions are asked one at a time on separate pages alternating between categories, so Category 1 then 2 then 3 then back to 1. Questions are setup with the Likert field with scoring enabled from 1 to 5. I would like to calculate and display the average of each category, and then another "score" calculated by multiplying each category average together. I would like the scores to be displayed on a confirmation page rounded to 1 decimal point.

I have attempted to use hidden number fields to calculate each average with merge tags and then output the number field merge tag to the confirmation page since as far as I know you cannot do calculations directly on the confirmation page. However, the number field merge tag outputs 0, and even a plain Likert field merge tag outputs the label instead of the 1-5 value. In the form its self the number field calculations are way off with 6 or 7 digit numbers, even when just using the field ID merge tag all alone in the number field calculation I get a 7 digit number. I don't think the Likert values are properly calculating.

Contacting GF support I was able to et them to give me this code which modifies the survey merge tag to display the value instead the label, however this does not work with the merge tags used in the form calculations. Only on the confirmation form post submission does it display the correct number.

```
add_filter( 'gform_merge_tag_filter', 'survey_score_modifier', 10, 4 );
function survey_score_modifier( $value, $merge_tag, $modifier, $field ) {

    if ( $field->type == 'survey' AND $modifier == 'score') {

        foreach ( $field->choices as $choice) {
            if ( $choice['text'] == $value ) {
                return $choice['score'];
            }
        }

    }

    return $value;

}
```

I was told score for the likert field was stored in the form object and was a random number for security reasons.

I would like to know how to either capture the likert field score for every field in the form and be able to do calculations before the form submission, or redirect after submission to a page where I can run calculations with merge tags.

Thanks.

Comment: You can post a URL string to the confirmation page, and pull results from that.  I've done something similar and that's how I accomplished it.

Comment: Just gave this a try. Even which the merge tag filter it looks like it outputs the field label instead of the score value. 

http://rleeconsulting.com/self-assessment-results/?Rarely+but+Effective+or+Often+but+Marginally+Effective#gf_4